# Pulling complex data from other sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to pull data for an NFL games tracker.  Data comes from other sheets but the combination in which I need it is pretty specific and I cannot get it to work.

I need a player's three-letter team combination to be looked up to find team names then looked up again to find scores for those specific teams in that specific week then added up.

I also need the top four and bottom, four teams, to be looked up and added.

An additional challenge is using formulas that can be pasted to subsequent weeks without error.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bV8QGQyHw8LuxYwdyhQrtqnKXubVc9J6ARrkKnGx50U/edit?usp=sharing

Please see notes in cells B2, C2, and D3 of sheet "Fam."

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: While a linked spreadsheet could be helpful, all the relevant details should be included on the question itself becasue the access to the linked spreadsheet could be lost.

Comment: I'm sorry!  I have fixed the view settings.  Thanks Ruben, I will try to explain better in the text!